# Rss will not parse

Tags: javascript, php, xml, rss

I've been experimenting with xml data but I found an xml file with a structure that I've never seen before. I tried to call it using php and log it in the console but no luck any idea as to why? When I try this method with other files there seems to be no issue, for example, if you replace the url with this one "http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss" it works fine. Code is below

PHP

```
$xml = "https://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/display.php?stid=KATL";



echo file_get_contents($xml);
```

JS

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "metar.php");

xhr.onload = function (response) {
    var res = this.response;
    console.log(res);

}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Why bother relaying the hit through the server? Just have the xhr.open() target that URL directly.

Comment: Originally I created a service that parsed xml data and I found that using the php method for requesting the urls allowed me to get around previous issues with CORS. But thank you lol I feel kind of foolish for not trying this in the first place

Comment: But @AlexHowansky do you know why it wouldn't work when I requested it with php?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your script, but with the resource you are requesting. The web server is returning the "forbidden" status code.

You should probably check the https and the url.